# Getting filter within a function to work with tidy evaluation

Tags: r, dplyr, rlang

I'm trying to use dplyr to filter based on a dynamic variable.

I've figured out that to get filter to work, I need to enclose the variable name in parentheses.  However, if I program this into a fuction, it does not work properly.

```
df_ex <- data.frame(a = 1:10, b = 11:20)

param <- quo(a)

# returns df_ex with column a, only, as expected
df_ex %>%
dplyr::select(!!param)

# returns expected df
df_ex %>%
dplyr::filter((!!param)==5)

# Now for the function
testfun <- function(test_df, filt_var){
   filt_var_mod <- quo(filt_var)

   test_df %>%
    dplyr::filter((!!filt_var_mod)==5)
}

# returns empty df, not as expected
testfun(df_ex, "a")
```

I would like to learn to find the answers to these questions types of questions about dplyr for myself, so please feel free to refer me to the relevant part of the [programming vignette](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html)

Answer (score 5):

If your function accepts column name as character, then there is no need to quote it, on the other hand you need to convert it to a symbol and evaluate them in the `filter` function immediately with `UQ` or `!!` in the `nse` syntax:

```
testfun <- function(test_df, filt_var){
    test_df %>%
        dplyr::filter((!!rlang::sym(filt_var)) == 5)
}

testfun(df_ex, "a")
#  a  b
#1 5 15
```

---

If you want to type the column names without quotes, then you need `enquo`, which

> *takes a symbol referring to a function argument, quotes the R code that was supplied to this argument, captures the environment where the
>   function was called (and thus where the R code was typed), and bundles
>   them in a quosure.*

```
testfun <- function(test_df, filt_var){
    filt_var_mod <- enquo(filt_var)
    test_df %>%
        dplyr::filter((!!filt_var_mod) == 5)
}

testfun(df_ex, a)
#  a  b
#1 5 15
```

Answer (score 3):

Technically you don't need rlang or tidyeval or tibbles or dplyr for this kind of problem, base R leaves practically no sacred cows with what you can do using quote, eval, parse, and the other NSE tools that are baked in from the bottom up.

*Edit: Much more elegant solution proposed by @thelatemail*

```
df_ex <- data.frame(a = 1:10, b = 11:20)

testfun <- function(test_df, filt_var) {
  test_df[test_df[,filt_var] == 5,]
}    

testfun(df_ex, "a")
```

Returns

```
  a  b
5 5 15
```

Just for fun, a  data.table option could work as well:

```
library(data.table)

df_ex <- data.frame(a = 1:10, b = 11:20)

testfun <- function(test_df, filt_var) {
  setDT(test_df,key = filt_var)[.(5)]
}

testfun(df_ex, "a")
```

Returns:

```
   a  b
1: 5 15
```

Comment: Or just `test_df[test_df[,filt_var] == 5,]` and do away with all this eval, parse, etc etc. Using `$` interactively is just asking for trouble - `fortunes::fortune(312)`

Comment: Ha! that's a far simpler solution, didn't know that was even possible!

Comment: For anyone coming along later, `df_ex[which(eval(parse(text = paste0("test_df$",filt_var))) == 5),]` is the nonsense I had wrapped in the original body of the base-R function.

Comment: Yep, `$` is just an interactive shortcut to `[[` essentially. Also, `fortune(106)` is relevant here - "*If the answer is parse() you should usually rethink the question.*" :-P

Comment: I actually really like the elegant base R solution proposed.  I am however surprised that dplyr makes this so unnecessarily complex.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the scoped versions verbs can be used in place of tideval when making simple functions.

For example, if you want to pass the name as a string in your function, `filter_at` is an option.

Below is what using `filter_at` looks like with your variable as a string.  You pass the variables you want to filter on and then give the predicate function within either `all_vars` or `any_vars`.  With filtering with a single variable it doesn't matter which of those you use.

```
filter_at(df_ex, "a", all_vars(. == 5) )

 a  b
1 5 15
```

`filter_at` can easily be used in a function.

```
testfun = function(test_df, filt_var){

    test_df %>%
        dplyr::filter_at(filt_var, all_vars(. == 5) )
}

testfun(df_ex, "a")

  a  b
1 5 15
```

Answer (score 0):

Base NSE appear to work, too:

```
testfun2 <- function(test_df, filt_var){
  filt_var_mod <- substitute(filt_var)
  test_df %>% 
    dplyr::filter(eval(filt_var_mod) == 5)
}

testfun2(df_ex, a)


  a  b
1 5 15
```